# AutoFixture not recognizing frozen object

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, autofixture

AutoFixture does not recognize frozen object when filling dependencies.

```
public class Beta : IBeta
{
    private string text;

    public Beta(string text)
    {
        this.text = text;
    }
}  

public class Alpha : IAlpha
{
    public IBeta beta;

    public Alpha(IBeta beta)
    {
        this.beta = beta;
    }
}

public void Test()
{
    var fixture = new Fixture();

    IBeta beta = fixture.Freeze<IBeta>(new Beta("test"));
    IAlpha alpha = fixture.Create<Alpha>();
}
```

Yes, Alpha not IAlpha, because I want real Alpha with dependencies filled by AutoFixture.

PROBLEM: **'alpha.beta' is always CastleProxy, not my injected 'a' object...**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `Inject` instead of `Freeze`:

```
public void Test()
{
    var fixture = new Fixture();

    fixture.Inject<IBeta>(new Beta("test"));
    IAlpha alpha = fixture.Create<Alpha>();
}
```

The `Freeze` overload in the OP is for supplying a seed value, which, by default, is ignored by AutoFixture.

This is a [known design error on my part](https://github.com/AutoFixture/AutoFixture/issues/151) - sorry about the confusion.

Comment: The case here is I also want to use this 'beta' object later on (for test setup/verification), so I have to extend your code with 'var beta = new Beta("test");' first. That makes it 3 lines instead of 1, I think I will write an extension method for this. Thank you for explanation.

Comment: @one_mile_run Perhaps this isn't what you need, but just in case: you can use AutoFixture as an auto-mocking container: http://blog.ploeh.dk/2010/08/19/AutoFixtureasanauto-mockingcontainer

Comment: Yes, I really like auto-mocking feature and I use it a lot. However in this case I have to pass some fixed connection string to 'beta' object, so I had to create it manually.

Answer (score 0):

I created an extension method. It solves my problem.

```
public static class AutoFixtureExtensions
{
    public static TSeed FreezeSeed<TSeed>(this IFixture fixture, TSeed seed)
    {
        fixture.Inject<TSeed>(seed);
        return seed;
    }
}
```

Before:

```
IBeta beta = new Beta("test");
fixture.Inject<IBeta>(beta);

IAlpha alpha = fixture.Create<Alpha>();
beta.foo();
```

After v1:

```
// little gain in such use case
IBeta seed = new Beta("test");
IBeta beta = fixture.FreezeSeed<IBeta>(seed);

IAlpha alpha = fixture.Create<Alpha>();
beta.foo();
```

After v2:

```
// more self-describing
IBeta beta = fixture.FreezeSeed<IBeta>(new Beta("test"));

IAlpha alpha = fixture.Create<Alpha>();
beta.foo();
```

Actually, maybe not big difference, but it's more convenient and clear for me (than version with Inject()).